# Oracle database 11: select * from table fails

Tags: oracle, select

I have a weird issue. In one of the production DB servers we are trying to run

```
select * from SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME
```

When we run the query we are getting invalid identifier error. But when we select a particular column and run the same select query on the same table , we are able to get the output.

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

Please help me to understand the root cause.

Type created:

```
create or replace 
TYPE           "TEST_TYPE" is object
(
MULTIROW_ID VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
LOSS_ENTRY_TYPE VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR),
SUB_CATEGORY    VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR),
LOSS_AMOUNT NUMBER,
LOSS_ENTRY_CURR  VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
);
```

Type 2 created:

```
create or replace 
TYPE           "TEST_TYPE1" AS TABLE OF TEST_TYPE;
```

Main create table query using above table type columns:

```
CREATE TABLE "MS_TEST_DATA" 
   (    "REGION" VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR), 
    "Entries" "TEST_TYPE1" , 
    "ILE_DET_FUNCTION_OF_DISC_COM" VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)
   )
    NESTED TABLE "Entries" STORE AS "TEST_TYPE3";
```

If I run this locally, I am able to access the table with `select *` query.
but in server I don't have all the accesses. There I have read-only access to tables. I can only run `select *` queries.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Post your code (as text). Highlight line #39.

Comment: Is it a real table, not a view, materialized view, cte, query, ... ?

Comment: Its real table. but nested table

Comment: You still haven't shown us exactly what line 39 in your script is. Are your object, table and column names the same in production as in your local test, and what you've shown? Are you using the same client and version when querying both environments?

Comment: Most of the time, a "weird issue" issue turns out to be the difference between what we think we're doing and what we're actually doing.

Comment: line 39 is the line where i executed the select statement in sql developer

Comment: Now i am able to do select * from the mentioned table above. Is this some type of issue while we provide only select grant to the schema?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using  double quotes in DDL scripts. If it is system generated, write a script to eliminate double quotes wherever possible.